# Maven release plugin user input security

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I want to use the maven-release-plugin to release my application. However,
I found that the user input is not very securised. I want to know if it's possible to do as parameter :

- type patch to increment last number version (1.0.X+1)
- type minor to increment middle number version (1.X+1.O)
- type major to increment first number version(X+1.0.0)

Avoid putting 0.0.4 when the 0.0.5 is already released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let Jenkins construct the command line parameter `-DreleaseVersion` for you. The build-helper plugin with the goal `build-helper:parse-version` allows you to get a lot of useful Maven properties, including the actual and next number for major, minor and incremental.